# The concept of virtual host and DNS

Tags: dns, apache

I have a dedicated server and a mydomain.com (bought from a hosting company). I want to host a website from my dedicated server with the domain mydomain.com i.e. when I enter mydomain.com from browser it should point to the IP(let's say X.X.X.X) of dedicated server(and a particular folder inside it). I have some following queries:

**In Server**

1. I know I need to edit some of the files (like: host or hostname file) in the server but I do not know what exact file I need to edit.
2. How to add a Site enable or Site available in apache2 ?

**In Hosting Company control Panel**

1. Which records to add (A or cname or anyother)?
2. Where Should I add DNS(in dedicated server section or domain name section)?
3. How it is going to affect the behaviour of the domain?

in short the question is: **How the virtual host works & how to add DNS?**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly setup a A record to the IP address of your server. You need not add any DNS entries.

You then have to set up Virtual Hosts in Apache, refer [here](http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configure_apache_to_use_virtual_hosts_on_ubuntu_server) or [here](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache22_vhosts.php). While setting up virtual hosts, select the folder as per your needs.

Comment: Does it not matter where the nameserver records are as to if the OP needs to set up the DNS on his/her server or on the registar's server (I've not used Apache so this is how I did it)?

Comment: There is no need for DNS entry, updating the A record of the domain name is enough

Comment: Cool, so it is the same regardless - I guess it would be. @Subhransu Just to clarify the only *real* reason to move the name server to your own server is due to very complex set ups or (as in my case) faults with the server's nameserver records!